# enlarging an image without using popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to create a product details tab within a table with a clickable image. Clicking the image enlarges the image but problem is image width doesn't enlarge. I couldn't figure out what causing the problem. I'm also using bootstrap 5.3. here is my html and javascript code.

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="8" class="collapsible-content hidden">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl p-0 d-flex justify-content-start overflow-hidden">
          <a id="resizeButton"><img id="resim" src="img/mandalina.jpg" alt="" srcset="" width="100%" style="float: left" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl col-auto d-flex text-align-start">
          <p style="text-align: start">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis ad, accusantium porro saepe voluptatibus fugiat blanditiis, earum aliquid rem, cum dolores nihil ullam illo placeat itaque quidem fuga esse ipsum recusandae
            adipisci soluta. Vitae ea, quod corrupti, voluptatem illum magnam placeat quisquam necessitatibus fugiat dolore dolor eligendi? Hic iure tenetur in saepe, fugit dolor assumenda. Aspernatur, ratione voluptatibus neque
            explicabo quaerat est eos ullam porro dolorem cum commodi ipsa recusandae consequatur amet blanditiis. Nobis ut iusto ducimus deserunt labore laborum laboriosam aperiam illo itaque nostrum eos praesentium, aut
            reprehenderit accusamus maiores debitis animi facilis ratione ea culpa quibusdam, illum magnam!
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

```
var resim = document.getElementById("resim");
var originalWidth = resim.style.width; // keeping the orignal width

document.getElementById("resizeButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (resim.style.width === "150%") {
    resim.style.width = originalWidth; // turns back the original witdh
  } else {
    resim.style.width = "150%"; // makes the width 150%
  }
});
```

i tried giving the columns auto width but no luck also tried giving z-index for image div didn't work either

Comment: Can you add the complete code for demo or you can simply create a  codepen(https://codepen.io/). It will make easy to debug your issue.

Comment: Please don't use css inline styles and don't use tables, this is old fashioned, use correct hmtl semantic elements.

and if you want to change the stylings with an event, add classes
document.getElementById("resizeButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
 resim.classList.toggle('bigger');
});

bigger-class:
.bigger {
transform: scale(3);
}

Comment: `var originalWidth = resim.style.width; // keeping the orignal width` - have you _verified_ that is what you are actually getting here ...? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/width: _"The width property of the HTMLImageElement interface indicates **the width at which an image is drawn** in CSS pixels if it's being drawn or rendered to any visual medium such as a screen or printer."_

Answer (score 1):

You could open the image in fullscreen using `imgElement.requestFullscreen();` That way you don't have to change any styling.